# How to select an "empty element" inside the div and remove it with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, moodle

I have an block of code that is like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry-title">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
  </div>

  .... ....                                                    

</div>
```

I want to remove the line that contains the dots (generated by the system).

How I can remove using jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a roundabout solution.  But you can remove just the elements, clear everything and add just the elements back again.

Like this.

```
var contentDivs = $("div.container").find("*");
$("div.container").empty().append(contentDivs);
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/deZtd/3/